# jQuery AJAX Post method error (syntax error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I have a web page on a Linux machine that needs to run a Python script in one of my JavaScript functions.
The script is located on the server, same directory as the html file, and needs to run on the server, not on the client.

I'm trying to use the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "scripti.py",
    success: function(resultData) { alert("Success") },
    error: function(resultData) { alert("Error") }
});
```

and I get these errors (on Developer Tools):

```
syntax error     scripti.py:1:1
syntax error     tesla.html:1:1
```

The script, of course, runs fine manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think the IDE was expecting the callbacks, probably you should include the success and error event.

Comment: I added just now, still same errors... I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser **cannot execute python code**, it only runs Javascript so even if you download a python file it will not be executed. You need to run it on a server side :(

You are using jQuery to get a file. By default jQuery expect xml, json, script, or html format files so this is why you receive a syntax erreor

```
dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
Type: String
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are: ...
```

See [jQuery documetnation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You need to develop a webservice to call a URL with jQuery and your python application running on a server (using a REST API to return JSON).$
There is some work here, so expect to spend few days/weeks on it if you never worked on such an infrastructure.